# Function dependent to nth order on a sample

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

From  [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176348768):

> ... every multivariate density estimator that is in any reasonable sense nonparametric may be written in the form:
>
> $$ \hat{f}(y) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_n(x_i, y) $$
>
> where $K_n$ is asymptotically a Dirac evaluation functional at $y$.  This almost, but not quite, says that all nonparametric density estimators are kernel estimators, since $K_n$ may be dependent to second order on the other sample points.

It is not clear to me what "dependent to second order on the other sample points" means in this context.  Note that the subscript $n$ on $K_n$ refers to the sample size, not the other points.  What is meant by "dependent to the $n$th order on a sample"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the more formal version of the statement:

> Theorem 1. Any multivariate density estimator that is a continuous and Gâteaux differentiable functional on the empirical distribution function may be written as
>   $$ \hat f(y) = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n K(x_i, y, \hat F_n),$$
>   where $K$ is the Gâteaux derivative of $\hat f$ under variation of $x_i$.

$\hat F_n$ is the empirical distribution, i.e. the measure which puts a point mass at every observed data point.

In the informal version you quoted, then, $K_n$ is not simply some function that changes in a fixed way as $n \to \infty$ (e.g. by shrinking a bandwidth); it can potentially depend on *all* of the observed data. I think this is what they mean by "*$K_n$ may be dependent to second order on the other sample points*": the $K_n$ function can depend on the interactions between multiple $x_i$, not simply one at a time as is implied by the way they wrote it in (1.5).

The reason they give for saying this is that because as $n \to \infty$, $\hat F_n \to F$ (the true distribution), $K$ asymptotically does not depend on any other single data point, and so asymptotically you can throw away the dependence on $\hat F_n$ to simple dependence on $n$.

(I'm a little skeptical of this argument without thinking about it more deeply; although indeed $K$ doesn't asymptotically depend on any single data point other than $x_i$, it can asymptotically depend on $F$! And indeed in the regime where $\hat F_n \approx F$, surely the best thing for $K$ to do is simply to have $K(x_i, y, F)$ ignore $x_i$ and return the density of $F$ at $y$. Maybe this is effectively precluded by the definition of $K$ as a derivative of $\hat f$, but it's not immediately obvious to me why that would be.)